# PHP funções parametos

Tags: php, if, funções, else

Sou novo em php e estou criando uma comparação de tamanhos de caixas, e para isso gostaria de colocar dentro de uma função mais não sei qual o parameto colocar dentro do parentes da função.
Alguem poderia me ajudar, Obrigado.

```
<?php 
include("caixa.php");
function CalcularCaixa()// não sei o que colocar dentro desse parentes
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['caixa'][$id]));
                    {   
                        if($id == 1)
                        {
                            if($quantidade >= 1)
                            {   
                                if($quantidade <= 50)
                                {
                                    echo $altura;
                                    echo $largura;
                                    echo $comprimento;
                                    echo $peso; 
                                }
                                elseif($quantidade <= 100)
                                {
                                    echo $altura * 2;
                                    echo $largura * 2;
                                    echo $comprimento * 2;
                                    echo $peso * 2;     
                                }
                                elseif($quantidade <= 150)
                                {
                                    echo $altura * 3;
                                    echo $largura * 3;
                                    echo $comprimento * 3;
                                    echo $peso * 3;     
                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nos `()` da função você passa os parâmetros necessários para que a sua função execute determinada tarefa.

Exemplo: Você tem a função `Soma`, que irá somar 2 números.

1º a função irá somar 2 números, logo precisamos obter esses 2 números para que a função possa fazer a soma, então podemos passar esses 2 números por parâmetro.

```
<?php
public function($num1, $num2){
    echo "A soma dá: ".$num1 + $num2;
}

// usando a função;
soma(1,2);
?>
```

Recomendo que você de uma lida nesses links, para entender melhor a passagem de parâmetros:

[PHP: Argumentos de Função](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.arguments.php)

[Funções: passagem de parâmetros](http://www.ime.usp.br/~elo/IntroducaoComputacao/Funcoes%20passagem%20de%20parametros.htm)

[Passagem de Parâmetros](https://www.inf.pucrs.br/~manssour/LinguagemC++/PassagemParam.pdf)

Também é muito útil, visitar o [codeacademy de php](http://www.codecademy.com/pt-BR/tracks/php) que atualmente está  em português, para iniciantes é excelente, pois cobre desde a declaração de uma variável até funções mais complexas, podendo te ajudar a longo prazo.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda cara, vou dar uma olhada e tentar aqui obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso eu passaria um `array` `$caixa` com os atributos desejados:

```
<?php

function CalcularCaixa(array $caixa)
{
    if ($caixa['quantidade'] >= 1) {
        if ($caixa['quantidade'] <= 50) {
            return $caixa;
        } elseif ($caixa['quantidade'] <= 100) {
            $caixa['altura'] *= 2;
            $caixa['largura'] *= 2;
            $caixa['comprimento'] *= 2;
            $caixa['peso'] *= 2;
        } elseif ($caixa['quantidade'] <= 150) {
            $caixa['altura'] *= 3;
            $caixa['largura'] *= 3;
            $caixa['comprimento'] *= 3;
            $caixa['peso'] *= 3;
        }
    }

    return $caixa;
}

$caixa = $_SESSION['caixa'][1];
$caixaCalculada = CalcularCaixa($caixa);
```

A ideia é pensar como reutilizar a lógica em outros lugares da aplicação, nesse caso em outras caixas.

Comment: Obrigado pela idéia não tinha pensado em por um array vlw!

Comment: @LeonardoSilva caso alguma resposta tenha resolvido sua dúvida, você pode marcá-la como aceita. Leia mais em [tour].